# Removing blank / white spaces around signature generated with 'signature_pad'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove white space around my signature and I found one piece of code, which could help me do that; however, I am not getting how to use it.

['signature_pad'](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) is JS library that helps you draw signatures.

[Here](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/issues/49#issue-29108215) (**first comment posted by user efc**) is the code piece that I found.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcz87rgn/) (jsfiddle) is how I am trying to use that code but whenever I click "Save as PNG" button, I get the following error:

> signaturePad.toDataURL(...).removeBlanks is not a function

**Full code:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');

// Adjust canvas coordinate space taking into account pixel ratio,
// to make it look crisp on mobile devices.
// This also causes canvas to be cleared.
function resizeCanvas() {
    // When zoomed out to less than 100%, for some very strange reason,
    // some browsers report devicePixelRatio as less than 1
    // and only part of the canvas is cleared then.
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' // necessary for saving image as JPEG; can be removed is only saving as PNG or SVG
});

document.getElementById('save-png').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    return alert("Please provide a signature first.");
  }
  
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png').removeBlanks();
  console.log(data);
  window.open(data);
});


document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
  signaturePad.clear();
});


SignaturePad.prototype.removeBlanks = function () {
        var imgWidth = this._ctx.canvas.width;
        var imgHeight = this._ctx.canvas.height;
        var imageData = this._ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight),
        data = imageData.data,
        getAlpha = function(x, y) {
            return data[(imgWidth*y + x) * 4 + 3]
        },
        scanY = function (fromTop) {
            var offset = fromTop ? 1 : -1;

            // loop through each row
            for(var y = fromTop ? 0 : imgHeight - 1; fromTop ? (y < imgHeight) : (y > -1); y += offset) {

                // loop through each column
                for(var x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
                    if (getAlpha(x, y)) {
                        return y;                        
                    }      
                }
            }
            return null; // all image is white
        },
        scanX = function (fromLeft) {
            var offset = fromLeft? 1 : -1;

            // loop through each column
            for(var x = fromLeft ? 0 : imgWidth - 1; fromLeft ? (x < imgWidth) : (x > -1); x += offset) {

                // loop through each row
                for(var y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                    if (getAlpha(x, y)) {
                        return x;                        
                    }      
                }
            }
            return null; // all image is white
        };

        var cropTop = scanY(true),
        cropBottom = scanY(false),
        cropLeft = scanX(true),
        cropRight = scanX(false);

        var relevantData = this._ctx.getImageData(cropLeft, cropTop, cropRight-cropLeft, cropBottom-cropTop);
        this._canvas.width = cropRight-cropLeft;
        this._canvas.height = cropBottom-cropTop;
        this._ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cropRight-cropLeft, cropBottom-cropTop);
        this._ctx.putImageData(relevantData, 0, 0);
    };
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.signature-pad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>

<button id="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

**Can someone please explain to me how to use that function? I think I am not getting what this (prototype) part means:**

```
SignaturePad.prototype.removeBlanks = function () {...
```

Comment: Regarding `prototype`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: This adds a method to the `SignaturePad` class, so you need to call it on the instance of that, and not _after_ transforming the object to something completely different (a data URI) – `signaturePad.removeBlanks()`. And since this method does not seem to return the object itself, you can not use method chaining here. So you need to call `toDataURL` separately.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the help but I am not sure I am getting you...Can you please show it in code?

Comment: `signaturePad.removeBlanks(); var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');`

Comment: @04FS Now, it gives an error: > Cannot set property 'width' of undefined. at this line: `this._canvas.width = cropRight-cropLeft;`

Comment: Then I would guess that maybe something changed about how that library operates, so that this code perhaps doesn’t work together with a current version any more - it is from 2014 already after all.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the function on the `SignaturePad`'s prototype property, which mean it resides on that object. So correct way to execute that would be to call it on the `SignaturePad` object. i.e.

```
signaturePad.removeBlanks()
```

more information on the prototype property can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

However, from a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/blob/master/src/signature_pad.ts#L56), it looks like the structure has changed.

So your prototype function code should look something like;

```
SignaturePad.prototype.removeBlanks = function () {
    var imgWidth = this._ctx.canvas.width;
    var imgHeight = this._ctx.canvas.height;
            var imageData = this._ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight),
    data = imageData.data,
    getAlpha = function(x, y) {
        return data[(imgWidth*y + x) * 4 + 3]
    },
    scanY = function (fromTop) {
        var offset = fromTop ? 1 : -1;

        // loop through each row
        for(var y = fromTop ? 0 : imgHeight - 1; fromTop ? (y < imgHeight) : (y > 
         -1); y += offset) {

            // loop through each column
            for(var x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
                if (getAlpha(x, y)) {
                    return y;                        
                }      
            }
        }
        return null; // all image is white
    },
    scanX = function (fromLeft) {
        var offset = fromLeft? 1 : -1;

        // loop through each column
        for(var x = fromLeft ? 0 : imgWidth - 1; fromLeft ? (x < imgWidth) : (x > 
           -1); x += offset) {

            // loop through each row
            for(var y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                if (getAlpha(x, y)) {
                    return x;                        
                }      
            }
        }
        return null; // all image is white
    };

    var cropTop = scanY(true),
    cropBottom = scanY(false),
    cropLeft = scanX(true),
    cropRight = scanX(false);

    var relevantData = this._ctx.getImageData(cropLeft, cropTop, cropRight-cropLeft, cropBottom-cropTop);
    this._ctx.canvas.width = cropRight-cropLeft;
    this._ctx.canvas.height = cropBottom-cropTop;
    this._ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cropRight-cropLeft, cropBottom-cropTop);
    this._ctx.putImageData(relevantData, 0, 0);
};
```

and then call it on your `SignaturePad` instance;

```
signaturePad.removeBlanks();
```

and finally get the data;

```
var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Do note, I only compiled the code. Not tested